# Nested overrides in portal_skins folder

Tags: customization, plone, shortcut

How one could override files in nested portal_skins folder?

The default behavior seems to be that you need to copy whole folder structures if you want to override a single file. This is a maintenance nightmare.

E.g. how to override file:

```
Producs.TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/plugins/table/js/table.js
```

... without needing to create a duplicate for the whole Products.TinyMCE skins codebase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot), and put a file in your jbot template directory called Products.TinyMCE.skins.tinymce.plugins.table.js.table.js

Comment: Does jbot really work that way? I thought it only worked for browser view templates and viewlet templates and portlet templates i.e. ZCA technology.

Comment: From the pypi page: "CMF Objects: Any skin-object (e.g. images, templates) on the file system (directory views) can be overridden." It hooks in when the template is rendered so it doesn't really matter how it's traversed.

Comment: z3c.jbot has an impact on performances but is the best solutions.

Comment: I tested it! I confirm! It works also in this way!

I created a "Products.TinyMCE.skins.tinymce.plugins.table.editor_plugin.js" and this become the one called by Plone! Great!

Comment: @toutpt, it used to have about a 7% impact on performance but then Malthe rewrote it so it does the heavy lifting at startup. Are you sure it still slows things down?

Comment: If it does heavy lifting on start up it slows Plone restart, then? :(

Comment: Sure, probably a small amount. That's better than slowing down each request or not being able to override templates, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override parts of a nested skins folder structure. If you want to customize things, best to create a new tinymce plugin (like mytables) and copy only the files for that plugin.

Comment: I was more looking for an answer: you need to monkey-patch this and this and this :) But I might actually do it ugly way and have on startup script which will simply overwrite files on FS :(