# Render rich text widget manually in plone custom page

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I have a custom edit (browser page) for my dexterity content type. In template I have defined a form using Bootstrap and added some Angular JS code for form behavior. It is working. :)

I need to replace a simple textarea with rich text widget. So how can I render in my template the rich text widget (one that is normally used in dexterity)?

Comment: Unverified (so not an answer), but if you use plone.app.widgets to get your TinyMCE, you can likely invoke the pattern with simple declarative "pat-tinymce" class name: http://plone.github.io/mockup/dev/#pattern/tinymce  I'm not sure for Products.TinyMCE (TinyMCE 3.x) in Plone 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Mockup](http://plone.github.io/mockup/) (not sure if anybody use it on Plone 4) you can find tips there: [Obtaining the "default" mockup TinyMCE configuration on Plone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606898/obtaining-the-default-mockup-tinymce-configuration-on-plone-5)

Otherwise (the Plone 4.3 version of TinyMCE) it's only a matter of CSS classes and configurations.

```
 <textarea name="..."
     class="pat-tinymce mce_editable"
     data-mce-config JSONCONFIGURATION_HERE">
 </textarea>
```

I've an add-ons that enable TinyMCE on simple forms; look at the cose to find how to obtain the JSON configuration: See [rt.zptformfield](https://github.com/RedTurtle/rt.zptformfield).

I've also a blogpost about the approach I used there but it's in italian :-) - http://blog.redturtle.it/usare-widget-plone-in-semplici-template-html

Comment: Hi @keul, so rt.zptformfield looks pretty handy and also N.v.Gheem's WTForm has promises I'd like to explore the next time, adding a form. However, I forgot to mention I'm customizing an existing form (ATDocument). After reading more, I got the impression, one cannot do it without overriding the init-script using z3c.jbot. Some related links in the following comment, no surprise there's another blog-post of you amongst them :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161802/nested-overrides-in-portal-skins-folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394205/how-to-replace-b-with-strong-in-tinymce-for-plone http://blog.keul.it/2011/06/z3cjbot-magical-with-your-skins.html http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/wysiwyg.html#overriding-plug-in-resources

Answer (score 1):

It should suffice to apply the class `mceEditor` on the textarea.

If that shouldn't work, include the initialization in your template:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    elements : "id-of-textarea",
});
```

Comment: Gee, that worked before lunch, I sware. Now, not anymore. I would close this again, but cannot see a button...

Comment: P.S.: I think it used to work, when I used keul's snippet of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088348/how-to-set-focus-on-rich-text-field-in-edit-mode-of-a-contenttype/32089541#comment53018539_32089541 and executed tinyMCE.init() after its resources were loaded, but am afraid, I have no time now to reproduce it for confirmation.